# apt Wants to Uninstall Cuda?

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, cuda

The other day I updated to a newer version of nvidia driver. Today I ran apt upgrade and it says....

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  cuda-command-line-tools-8-0 cuda-core-8-0 cuda-cublas-8-0
  cuda-cublas-dev-8-0 cuda-cudart-8-0 cuda-cudart-dev-8-0 cuda-cufft-8-0
  cuda-cufft-dev-8-0 cuda-curand-8-0 cuda-curand-dev-8-0 cuda-cusolver-8-0
  cuda-cusolver-dev-8-0 cuda-cusparse-8-0 cuda-cusparse-dev-8-0
  cuda-documentation-8-0 cuda-driver-dev-8-0 cuda-license-8-0
  cuda-misc-headers-8-0 cuda-npp-8-0 cuda-npp-dev-8-0 cuda-nvgraph-8-0
  cuda-nvgraph-dev-8-0 cuda-nvml-dev-8-0 cuda-nvrtc-8-0 cuda-nvrtc-dev-8-0
  cuda-samples-8-0 cuda-toolkit-8-0 cuda-visual-tools-8-0 freeglut3-dev
  libxmu-dev libxmu-headers nvidia-modprobe
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
```

But my cuda works fine (Just tested a neural net against it) and I have no reason to want to remove them. Why and how to put a stop to this?

Answer (score 1):

This is old, but today I had this exact problem (actually my list of packages to be removed was much bigger, maybe a hundred, with other libraries like `libc6` or `libopencv`, and the single line below removed them all from auto-removal) and the solution is worth mentionning here I reckon.

As @fkraiem mentioned, reinstalling manually the packages will make Apt aware that you want to keep them. But it is not needed for all the list, and eventually you will install packages that will remain on the list if their dependencies is also marked for auto-removal.
Or you could also mark them manually (with `apt-mark manual <packages>` to mark `<packages>` that you do not want to be removed automatically).

However the *cleanest option*, in my opinion, as you only need to ask installation of one package, is to manually re-install the package at the root of this problem, namely:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit-8-0
```

and all the others dependencies will then be gone.

Comment: Re-installing did solve the problem. However today, it would be `sudo apt-get install cuda`.
Check Nvidia official documentation for Ubuntu here: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#common-installation-instructions-for-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Apt does not "want" to remove those packages, it is just letting you know that those packages were installed as dependencies of another package that is no longer installed, and so it is possible that you no longer need them either.

If you do need them, you can just do `sudo apt install packagename` to tell Apt that you really need a particular package; then it will no longer suggest that you uninstall that package or its dependencies.